.gitignore file not ignoring compiled executable file
I know this question has been asked before, that git has a documentation, but alas, here I am.
I'm programming a little C++ program and I use VS Code with mingw. My compiled file is named "main.exe" and is located on root directory of my repository. Same directory also has my .gitignore file and in it I'm only ignoring main.exe. It looks like this:
main.exe

When I run the command "git check-ignore -v main.exe" it returns nothing.
When I run "git add ." it stages main.exe and marks it as new.
Here's what I tried so far:
I ran "git rm --cached main.exe", committed my other changes, when I ran "git add ." it tracked main.exe again.
I ran "git rm -rf --cached .", then "git add .", lo and behold, it's staged again.
Then I read online that having main.exe on another branch might cause git to not respect .gitignore rules, so I deleted any other branch that included main.exe both on github and on my local git.
Did the first two steps again with only one branch to no avail.
What am I missing? Like, do you need to manually unstage any unwanted files every time? Maybe recompiling main.exe on source code change makes git think it's a new file? I just don't know. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I would happily provide my github link if need arises.

Don't be lazy, run git status and put each file that you need manually as an argument to git add.

Where is main.exe in relation to the gitignore? Please may you share that information, plus the relevant part of the gitignore as well

You should exclude target build directories in .gitignore in the root of your repository. Because I am sure you will need to ignore a lot more intermediate build files anyway

Is this what's going on here?

@evolutionxbox main.exe and .gitignore files are on the root directory of the repository. As stated on the first paragraph.

main.exe #not specifying any path because it's on the root directory. This is a wrong .gitignore content. Comments can start only on new lines.

@jthill It really was! Changing to UTF-8 encoding fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!

@3CxEZiVlQ Yeah, it actually is just 'main.exe' on my .gitignore file. The comment is only present here. I'll remove it from the question.
